# How to a add a nested parent node to an existing node

Tags: c#, xml

I have generated an xml by using `DataTable.WriteXML()` method, which converts my table fields into elements of an xml file - that's precisely what I need.

Now I want to add another element and make an existing element as its child.

Existing:

```
<DocketImport>
  <Docket>
    <XRefCode>1578</XRefCode>
    <Name>1578</Name>
    <PieceRate>0</PieceRate>
    <OrgXRefCode>terminalA</OrgXRefCode>
  </Docket>
</DocketImport>
```

Desired:

```
<DocketImport>
  <Docket>
    <XRefCode>1578</XRefCode>
    <Name>1578</Name>
    <PieceRate>0</PieceRate>
    <Org>        
     <OrgXRefCode>terminalA</OrgXRefCode>
    </Org>
  </Docket>
</DocketImport>
```

Comment: Try using [XmlDocument.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_IO_Stream_). I think you can modify the object using methods like [xmldocument.CreateElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlDocument_CreateElement_System_String_) and [element.AppendChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_AppendChild_System_Xml_XmlNode_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case following result would be acceptable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <DataTable1>
    <XRefCode>1578</XRefCode>
    <Name>1578</Name>
    <PieceRate>0</PieceRate>
    <Org xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <OrgXRefCode>terminalA</OrgXRefCode>
    </Org>
  </DataTable1>
</DocumentElement>
```

You can achieve desired behavior by defining custom type for last columns of your DataTable

```
public class Org
{
    public string OrgXRefCode { get; set; }
}
```

Than your DataTable initialization could look as following:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable("DataTable2");

dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{
    new DataColumn("XRefCode"),
    new DataColumn("Name"),
    new DataColumn("PieceRate"),
    new DataColumn("Org", typeof(Org))
});

var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow["XRefCode"] = 1578;
dataRow["Name"] = 1578;
dataRow["PieceRate"] = 0;
dataRow["Org"] = new Org()
{
    OrgXRefCode = "terminalA"
};

dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

calling `dataTable.WriteXml()` will produce your expected XML

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working perfectly as I needed :)